# Python boto3 script fails to get a instance tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to get value of Tag key `AutoScalingGroupName` of  instance. Python boto3 script fails with syntax error.

Here is my sample script.

```
#!/bin/python3.4
import requests
import boto3
import botocore.session
import urllib.request

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-1', aws_access_key_id='****************', aws_secret_access_key='****************************')
liid = urllib.request.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read().decode()
autoinstinfo = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[liid], Filters=[{'Name':'tag:AutoScalingGroupName', 'Values':['%s']} % ['AutoScalingGroupName']).get( 'Reservations', [] )
print(autoinstinfo)
```

Fails with this error message.

> ## python3.4 ./test.py
>
> File "./test.py", line 9
>   autoinstinfo = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[liid], Filters=[{'Name':'tag:AutoScalingGroupName', 'Values':['%s']} % (AutoScalingGroupName)).get( 'Reservations', [] )
>                           ^
>      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use string format when you know the tag name? Why can't the following work?

```
ec2.describe_tags(Filters=[{'Name':'resource-id', 'Values':[liid]}, {'Name':'key', 'Values':['AutoScalingGroupName']}])['Tags'][0]['Value']
```

Comment: I am just getting empty dict ? `[]`

Comment: `# python3.4 ./test.py
[]

Comment: I didn't notice any errors, but I got all information this running instance. Need only "AutoScalingGroupName" value. Is something I am missing in print statement ?

Comment: @bobby you are over complicating. If you just want the tag value, use the one I just updated. If you know python, you know how to handle if such a tag doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, It worked great, I should be using `ec2.describe_tags`.

Answer (score 1):

```
`import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()

for r in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in r['Instances']:
        Tags = instance['Tags'][0]['Key']
        print(Tags)`
```

Above script will give you tags-key of all instances in your aws account.

Comment: Above script will give you tags-key of all instances in your aws account